# dispatch proxy works only with firefox

Tags: linux, proxy

I installed dispatch-proxy on Lubuntu 14.10 from instructions here: https://github.com/Morhaus/dispatch-proxy

The problem is the SOCKS proxy works with firefox but not with fatrat or curl. I'm puzzled.

Fatrat times out after waiting for reply from the proxy server. curl simply hangs.

I also observed same problem with fedora 20.

I have no idea why this is happening, could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a bug in dispatch-proxy 0.1.2. This is fixed in 0.1.3.

https://github.com/Morhaus/dispatch-proxy/issues/38

Comment: Can you cite a reference for this where people can go for further information?